# ¿Error en añadir más de una vez la misma regla .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Tengo la siguiente regla que me permite crear, múltiples categorías, en la `URL`, sin necesidad de escribir las categorías en mi `.htaccess`, por ejemplo: `RewriteRule ^mundial/(...`

Sino que directamente desde la siguiente regla:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+/?)$ detail.php?id=$2&categories=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+/?)$ detail_one.php?id=$2&categories=$1
```

Puedo tener un sin número de categorías en la URL, por ejemplo: `example.com/categoria/mundial/otras/muchasmas/url-del-post/`

Ahora mi problema es, que tengo detalles de productos individuales, creado por archivos individuales `detail.php`, `detail_one.php` entre otras.

La cual solo me funciona una de las reglas `.htaccess`, es decir tengo que desactivar `#` una de ellas, para que el detalle de los productos del archivo `detail.php` muestre los detalles y para que se muestre el detalle del archivo `detail_one.php` tengo que desactivar la regla `.htaccess` del archivo `detail.php`

¿Cómo puedo hacer para poder conservar el mismo diseño de múltiples categorías, pero que la misma regla me permita añadir más de una, para los diferentes detalles de noticias?

Comment: Hola Eduardo. Debería haber algo en la url que redirecciona a 'detail.php' que nos permita diferenciarla de la url que redirecciona a 'detail_one.php'. Tienen algo esas urls que nos permita distinguirlas?

Comment: Pues deberían tener alguna diferencia, si no, ejecutará la primera regla existente. Es el problema que tenías en una pregunta anterior. Una posible manera sería que las que van a detail_one terminen en "/one" (después de la url) o que tengan un "/one" antes (como si fuese la primera categoria). Pero hay que distinguirlas de alguna manera

Comment: Primero piensa como quieres montar las urls. Otra opción sería `midominio.com/detailone/cat1/cat2/url` para detail_one y `midominio.com/cat1/cat2/url` para detail.php. Hay varias opciones. Lo importante es que viendo esas urls puedas distinguir entre una u otra

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80911/discussion-between-julio-and-eduardo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como hemos discutido en el chat, no puedes tener la misma regla repetida y esperar que te redireccione a distintos phps. Las urls deben tener algo diferente con lo que distinguirlas. Algo por lo que empiece o acabe, por ejemplo. Si no, lo que hará es procesar siempre la primera regla de las dos.

Así pues, haremos que las páginas que vayan a detail tengan esta forma: `midominio.com/categoria1/categoria2/mi-url`. Mientras que las que van a detail_one empezarán con un 1 delante: `midominio.com/1/categoria1/categoria2/mi-url`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+/?)$ detail.php?id=$2&categories=$1
RewriteRule ^1/(.*)/([^/]+/?)$ detail_one.php?id=$2&categories=$1
```

Si quisieras poner el 1 al final `midominio.com/categoria1/categoria2/mi-url/1`, podrías utilizar:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+/?)$ detail.php?id=$2&categories=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+/)1/?$ detail_one.php?id=$2&categories=$1
```

Comment: Gracias amigo :)